# Row Click Refresh DetailsView Only Without Refresh Entire Page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am new to ASP.NET and needed help. Basically, I have a GridView1 and the DetailsView1 on the the same page. What I want to do is when user clicks on the row, it will ONLY refresh the DetailsView1 area for that particular record.  The following code is working for view the record in the DetailsView1 area, but it also refresh entire page. Please advise with a sample codes if possible.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="TrackID" ShowFooter="True" 
    AllowPaging="True" PageSize="8"
     SelectedIndex="0" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"

     OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging"
     OnPageIndexChanged="GridView1_PageIndexChanged" OnRowDeleted="GridView1_RowDeleted" OnSorted="GridView1_Sorted"
    OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting"

     ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No records Found"

     EnableRowClick = "True" Width="100%" AllowSorting="True"                         
>
    /.....  Fields Are Here ...../
</asp:GridView>


<asp:DetailsView AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="TrackID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
    HeaderText="Project Detail" ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Width="100%" OnItemUpdated="DetailsView1_ItemUpdated" 
        OnItemInserted="DetailsView1_ItemInserted"  OnDataBound="DetailsView1_DataBound"
    validateRequest="false" RowStyle-BackColor="White" OnItemDeleted="SqlDataSource2_ItemDeleted"                    
    >
    /.....  Fields Are Here ...../
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Code Behind:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim RowNum As Integer
        RowNum = e.Row.RowIndex

        If RowNum Mod 2 = 1 Then

            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='LightCyan'")

        Else

            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'")

        End If

        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='LightBlue'")
        e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Me.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(Me.GridView1, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
    End If
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thank you. I will look at the ""Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"

Comment: If you are a JavaScript/Json expert, you might be able to do this but otherwise the best you can hope for is using an AJAX Update Panel (or something like it) to refresh the entire grid, but at least it is not your whole page.